# Get grouped product ID

Tags: magento

If I have have the product ID of an item that is part of a grouped product, is there a way to get the product ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what. Ill try and decipher what you mean. You could use the group_id and search for all other product_ids with the same group_id.